# Using pointers to make a new string in function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I am doing a bit of studying about C pointers and how to transfer them to functions, so I made this program

```
    #include <stdio.h>
char* my_copy(pnt);
void main()
{
    int i;
    char a[30];
    char* p,*pnt;
    printf("Please enter a string\n");
    gets(a);
    pnt = a;
    p = my_copy(pnt);
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        printf("%c", p[i]);

}
char* my_copy(char* pnt)
{
    char b[3];
    char* g;
    g = pnt;
    b[0] = *pnt;
    for (; *pnt != 0; pnt++);
    pnt--;
    b[1] = *pnt;
    b[2] = NULL;


    return b;
    }
```

It's supposed to take a string using only pointers and send a pointer of the string to the function `my_copy` and return a pointer to a new string which contains the first and the last letter of the new string. Now the problem is that the `p` value does receive the 2 letters but I can't seem to print them. Does anyone have an idea why?

Comment: You may not return a pointer to a local variable. Such a pointer will be invalid because the object pointed to by the pointer will not be alive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see five issues with your code:

1. `char* my_copy(pnt);` is wrong. A function prototype specifies the types of the parameters, not their names. It should be `char *my_copy(char *)`.
2. `void main()` is wrong. `main` should return `int` (and a parameterless function is specified as `(void)` in C): `int main(void)`.
3. `gets(a);` is wrong. Any use of `gets` is a bug (buffer overflow) and `gets` itself has been removed from the standard library. Use `fgets` instead.
4. `b[2] = NULL;` is a type error. `NULL` is a pointer, but `b[2]` is a `char`. You want `b[2] = '\0';` instead.
5. `my_copy` returns the address of a local variable (`b`). By the time the function returns, the variable is gone and the pointer is invalid. To fix this, you can have the caller specify another pointer (which tells `my_copy` where to store the result, like `strcpy` or `fgets`). You can also make the function return dynamically allocated memory, which the caller then has to free after it is done using it (like `fopen` / `fclose`).

Answer (score 1):

You're returning an array from `my_copy` that you declared within the function. This was allocated on the stack and so is invalid when the function returns.

You need to allocate the new string on the heap:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

    b = malloc(3);
    if (b) {
        /* Do your funny copy here */
    }
```

Don't forget to `free()` the returned string when you've finished with it.